# Access ProcessContext::forward from multiple user threads

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Given: DSL topology with KStream::transform. As part of Transformer::transform execution multiple messages are generated from the input one (it could be thousands of output messages from the single input message).

New messages are generated based on the data retrieved from the database. To speed up the process I would like to create multiple user threads to access data in DB in parallel. Upon generating a new message the thread will call ProcessContext::forward to send the message downstream.

Is it safe to call ProcessContext::forward from the different threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe and not allowed to call `ProcessorContext#forward()` from a different thread. If you try it, an exception will be thrown.

As a workaround, you could let all threads "buffer" their result data, and collect all data in the next call to `process()`. As an alternative, you could also schedule a punctuation that collects and forwards the data from the different threads.